# Failed to locate OpenSSL dependency building restbed on windows

Tags: windows, openssl, 64-bit, restbed

I'm trying to compile restbed with openssl on windows 10 using cmake 3.15.2.

I followed the instructions provided [here](https://github.com/corvusoft/restbed/issues/17#issuecomment-138083764)

and thus installed openssl following these :

```
cd restbed\dependency\openssl
perl Configure shared VC-WIN64A
nmake
nmake test
nmake install
```

I then build restbed with cmake:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=YES -DBUILD_TESTS=YES ..
```

But I always end up with this error :

```
CMake Error at cmake/Findopenssl.cmake:23 (message):
  Failed to locate OpenSSL dependency.  see restbed/dependency/openssl;
  ./config shared; make all
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (find_package)
```

Despite having used `shared` in my config command.

I looked into Findopenssl.cmake and most of the files searched are missing from my computer.

```
find_library( ssl_LIBRARY_STATIC libssl.a  ssleay32.lib HINTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl/out32dll" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl" "/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" "/usr/lib" "/usr/local/lib" "/opt/local/lib" )
find_library( crypto_LIBRARY_STATIC libcrypto.a libeay32.lib HINTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl/out32dll" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl" "/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" "/usr/lib" "/usr/local/lib" "/opt/local/lib" )

find_library( ssl_LIBRARY_SHARED libssl.so libssl.dylib ssleay32.dll HINTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl/out32dll" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl" "/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" "/usr/lib" "/usr/local/lib" "/opt/local/lib" )
find_library( crypto_LIBRARY_SHARED libcrypto.so libcrypto.dylib libeay32.dll HINTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl/out32dll" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl" "/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" "/usr/lib" "/usr/local/lib" "/opt/local/lib" )

find_path( ssl_INCLUDE openssl/ssl.h HINTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl/inc32" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl/include" "/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" "/usr/include" "/usr/local/include" "/opt/local/include" )
```

Besides, most of them seem to be linux paths.

I searched around and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54623729/findopenssl-cmake-fails-to-find-openssl-compiling-restbed-c) that's really similar, but working on a debian and not windows.
I didn't manage to find what's missing in my openssl installation.

Any idea what might be missing here ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the origin of the problem and its solution.

Here is [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55476623/cannot-find-libeay32-lib-and-ssleay32-lib-files-when-setting-up-openssl-on-windo)

Since openssl changed its libraries for `libcrypto.lib` and `libssl.lib` the current Findopenssl.cmake could not find what it was looking for : `libeay32.lib` and `ssleay32.lib.

I didn't manage to make it work by just changing their name in the `find_library`, so I just commented these and added these two lines Findopenssl.cmake :

```
set(ssl_LIBRARY_SHARED "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl")
set(crypto_LIBRARY_SHARED "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependency/openssl")
```

It's kind of dirty but works wonders.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another [answer](https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/issues/115#issuecomment-232827024)

```
cd restbed/dependency/openssl
./config; make
```